# Vagrant mount multiple folders on the same point - logout

Tags: macos, centos, vagrant, virtualbox

I try to NFS mount 3 folders into my own vagrant box (I created this box with CentOS),
but it seems always mount the folders on the same point (/home/vagrant/logout)

here is my Vagrantfile:

```rb
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "my_box"
  config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.100"
  config.ssh.pty = true

  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../Larvata/a", "/home/A", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../Larvata/b", "/home/B", type: "nfs"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../Larvata/c", "/home/C", type: "nfs"

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
  end
end
```

my vagrant up message:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Error: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Error: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
Password:
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.100.1:'/Users/zx1986/Larvata/A' logout

Stdout from the command:

export TERM=vt100
mount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.100.1:'/Users/zx1986/Larvata/B' logout
exit

export TERM=vt100
logoutmount -o 'vers=3,udp' 192.168.100.1:'/Users/zx1986/Larvata/C

mount.nfs: /home/vagrant/logout is busy or already mounted

exit
logout

Stderr from the command:
```

this /etc/exports generated by vagrant:

```
# VAGRANT-BEGIN: 501 
"/Users/zx1986/Box" 192.168.100.100 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
"/Users/zx1986/Larvata/a" 192.168.100.100 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
"/Users/zx1986/Larvata/b" "/Users/zx1986/Larvata/c" 192.168.100.100 -alldirs -mapall=501:20
# VAGRANT-END: 501
```

Virtaulbox 4.3.12
Vagrant 1.5.1
MacOS 10.9.3

Any idea or clues?
I have googled for a while, but haven't seem anything about the "logout" mount point.